# Android NDK crash in CallObjectMethod calling static method with ART

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

In an Android app I have some JNI code that calls a java static method.

```
jbyteArray response = (jbyteArray)pEnv->CallObjectMethod(handlerClass, mid, jstrServiceUrl, jstrRequest);
```

Executing it in Android 5 in an **ART** environment, I get a *check jni* error:

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: calling static method byte[] x.y.z(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) with CallObjectMethodV in call to CallObjectMethodV...

I don't get this error in Android 4 with a **Dalvik** environment.

The java method is this one:

```
public static byte[] z(String serviceURL, String request)
```

and is previously binded like this:

```
jclass handlerClass = pEnv->FindClass("x/y/z");
if (handlerClass == NULL) {
    return -1;
}

mid = pEnv->GetStaticMethodID(handlerClass, "z", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[B");
if (mid == NULL) {
    return -2;
}

// Construct Strings
jstring jstrServiceUrl = pEnv->NewStringUTF(szServiceURL);
jstring jstrRequest = pEnv->NewStringUTF(szRequest);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your code worked with Dalvik, but the method id given to `Call<type>Method` must be obtained with `GetMethodID`. If you have a method id obtained with `GetStaticMethodID` you should use `CallStatic<type>Method`.

See the descriptions of `Call<type>Method` and `CallStatic<type>Method` in [the JNI functions documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: @davide.web Could you please provide a snippet of the code that works? I have a similar problem but CallStaticVoidMethod() doens't work. I can't simply substitute CallVoidMethod() with CallStaticVoidMethod() or CallStaticObjectMethod()

Comment: @davide.web Aha! The difference between CallVoidMethod() and CallStaticVoidMethod() is that the first takes a parameter to an object and the CallStaticVoidMethod() takes a pointer to a class instead. Makes sense.